# Social Login with ionic - cache profile image?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, image-caching

Im getting memory issues when my splash screen loads. I think it may be due to my user profile images.

If the user doesn't have one (didn't log in with social media and hasn't updated their profile) I load/call an app logo image locally (200px x 200px).

```
<img class="avatar" ng-if="!userInfo.image" src="img/icon.png">
<img  class="avatar" ng-if="userInfo.image" ng-src="{{userInfo.image}}">
```

if the user updates their image on their profile its saves as a base64 string to the database and is called `userInfo.image`

How can i cache all the users images and call that image instead of making the service call.

The user's image is used often - on post, comments, likes, post link items - basically any reference to a users activity, their image is displayed.

When I list each item -  it calls the service in case the image has changed - the service pings Firebase and returns the following:

```
ProfileService.get(assigned, function(info){
                $scope.userInfo.status = info.status;
                $scope.userInfo.name = info.name;
                $scope.userInfo.image = info.image;
            });
```

can anyone help me get pointed in the right direction in cashing all the profile images. Im not even sure if this is causing the memory issues. This images are a max of 250px x 250px

Thank for your help.

Comment: Or if anyone has any suggestions on why calling a list of items would cause memory warnings in ios, please also comment with suggested fixes. Thank you!

Comment: I am just taking a guess here, but perhaps the base64 strings are just so long that they are causing memory issues? Did removing the images from the list make the errors completely disappear?

Comment: @dexter no I thought it had to do with too many service calls constructing the list

Comment: Anyone have any clues?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution but, you can save it in local storage and call it from there. [cordova localStorage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/6.x/cordova/storage/localstorage/localstorage.html)